# print json data in key,value pair using jquery

Tags: jquery, json, spring-mvc

I would like to print `{"abc":"abc","mno":"pqr","uvw":"xyz"}` in (key,value) format.

ex:`key=abc value=abc`

Below code is what I have tried. This does not work!
output is returned from controller.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<base href="<%=basePath%>">

<title>My JSP 'success.jsp' starting page</title>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript">
var container = $("div.container"); 
$(document).ready(function(){
    var val=$("#addressId").text();
    $.each(val,function(key,value){
        container.append("key :"+key+" value :"+value+"</br>");
    });

    $.each(val,function(key,value){
        $('.container1').append(key+"="+value+"</br>");
    });
});
</script>
 </head>
  <body>
This is my JSP page. <br>
<p id="addressId">${output}</p>
<div class="container">hi</div>
<div class="container1"></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly download and include the jquery library from https://jquery.com/. Then try the following code snippet.

```
var container = $("div.container"); 
$(document).ready(function(){
    var val={"abc":"abc","mno":"pqr","uvw":"xyz"};
    $.each(val,function(key,value){
        container.append(key+" = "+value+"</br>");
    });
});
```